# FHIR appointment book

Tags: hl7-fhir

Has anyone modelled a primary care appointment book using FHIR resources?

I'm wanting to model a book which allows slots to be held by more than one Practitioner (e.g. doctor and nurse), and a Location to be held against each Slot.

Currently I can't see a way of representing this, as a Schedule (and Slot by inference) can only be linked to one actor (Practitioner/Location etc).

Or if we create a seperate Schedule for each actor, how do you bundle the Practitioner and Location Slots together to create a single bookable entity?

Answer (score 0):

You do this using a healthcare resource as the placeholder that the practitioners are associated with.
And yes I would expect that each of the resources would have their own schedule and slots. This way you can detect conflicts for the individual resources when allocating practitioners to the apointment.

Depends on your business rules.

Will be doing this shortly too, and will share the learning's. Will be for a community clinic, then for gp services.

Brian